# ADMISSIONS Table, recent Mimic-III Postgres Updates

Tags: mimic-iii

Just updated my mimic-code directory after some changes were made yesterday to the postgres configuration files. Reimporting the data and getting the following error for the admissions table:

```
postgres=# \set admissions_csv :mimic_data_dir 'ADMISSIONS_DATA_TABLE.csv'
postgres=# COPY ADMISSIONS FROM :'admissions_csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "CHEST PAIN\CATH"
CONTEXT:  COPY admissions, line 2, column edregtime: "CHEST PAIN\CATH"
```

I know this is because the data I'm using is missing the edregtime column - is the appropriate data for these updates accessible on physionet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to load MIMIC-III (v1.1) data using the MIMIC-III (v1.2) build scripts. `edregtime` is a new column that was added [between v1.1 and v1.2](http://mimic.physionet.org/about/releasenotes/).

> Major issues addressed, including additional data made available:
>
> ...
>
> #151 - The time of emergency department registration and exit has been added to the admissions table, where available.

The latest version of the data can be downloaded from the MIMIC-III project page on [PhysioNet](https://physionet.org).